# A good way to make "back" / "prev" links for blog posts using pagination

Tags: php

**This post was closed but I thought I share my way of solving this problem with some easy pagination.**

What I will display here I will post in full so it will be much easier for someone else to make use of it, if they get stuck on the same part as I did.

What I am using here is the id from the database to get my posts, you can use title and whatnot, I am also sorting it to display the first post first. If you like to show the last one just change ASC to DESC at the bottom.

```
<?PHP
//Connect to the database
//Add your file here

//Get a record count of our database for pagination
$record_count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts");
//Number of posts displayed
$per_page = 2;
//Number of pages
$pages = ceil($record_count->num_rows/$per_page);
//Get page number
if(isset($_GET['p']) && is_numeric($_GET['p'])) {
$page = $_GET['p'];
}else{
$page = 1;
}
if($page<=0)
$start = 0;
else
//Make the controls to switch pages
$start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
$prev = $page - 1;
$next = $page + 1;
//Display the blog posts on the page
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, LEFT(message, 100) AS message, posted FROM posts ORDER BY post_id ASC LIMIT $start, $per_page");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $message, $posted);
?>
```

Then whatever html code you like, divs, p and what not and lastly I just echoed them out, some code is missing here but that is just my own code to display my own blog posts and their variables. To get the next and prev links at the bottom, use:

```
 <?PHP
            if($prev > 0) {
                echo "<a href='index.php?p=$prev'>Prev</a>";
            }
            if($page < $pages) {
                echo "<a href='index.php?p=$next'>Next</a>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/basic-pagination

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `id` field is your primary numerical key, instead of doing `id++`or `id--` to get the next/prev items, just use the current id as a reference. This will prevent you from accessing `id`'s that don't really exist.

**Current** item's SQL -

```
SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE id = '$id'
```

**Next** item's SQL -

```
SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE id > '$id' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

**Previous** item's SQL -

```
SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE id < '$id' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

If you are at the last/first item, and you request the prev/next item, these queries will return an empty result, because there is no item with an `id` less than `1` or more than the largest`id`.

Notice that I'm using the `LIMIT` keyword to make sure that I'm only getting one item in return; An item that has a bigger or smaller `id` value. The queries are already sorted by the `id` field so we will get sequential items from the table.

Comment: I like that idea with > and < however implementing it didn't go as expected and got me a few undefined variables for id and id2 can update my own question as I cant answer my own question...

Comment: @ang, it's better that you don't edit your original question to contain my answer - leave it as it was for other people to come and try help. It also makes my answer seem silly because I'm posting the same code you asked with :)

Comment: @ang, with regard to the undefined variables, I'm sure you had to change your code around to use the queries I gave you. Make sure that there were no errors made while you were moving the code around. My answer didn't modify the `$id` variable - only used it's current value as a reference.

Comment: Now I edited my first question back to it's original state as you said, I think... No, I actually did not change my code around other than the SELECT suggestions